# How to capture list of Change set id (hash) in Mercurial using python?

Tags: python, mercurial, pre-commit-hook

I'm newbie to both Mercurial and Python and I was thinking if its possible to capture list of all committed change set id (hash) and then iterate/loop through list of each change sets and print its hash (id) value one by one.

So far I've defined precommit hook in my mercurial.ini config file to fire a function:

### mercurial.ini

```
precommit = python: d:\workspace\Hello.py:precommit_printID
```

### Hello.py

```
def precommit_printID(ui, repo, *args, **kwargs):

  print ("ui: ", ui)
```

I mean its just basic and this is how far I've go into it, would be nice if you could show me how can that be done.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Generic pretxncommit/pretxnchangegroup Hook" on this page: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples

It shows exactly how to walk through the changesets being committed or pushed.

Comment: Ry4an - like I said in my question I'm new to python can show me a code snippet that prints change set Id (hashes) instead of redirecting me to a link which I not very clear to my standards!

Comment: Naw, if the really clear example on that page isn't getting you where you need to go this isn't going to end well.